# Populate data once ID is entered

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Example I have 3 input type=txt, userid, firstname and lastname from sql row table.
if I input and enter the userid,
firstname and lastname should appear on the input type.
is there anyway to do this? thank you
PHP/JS

Comment: You're looking for what is known as AJAX.

Comment: Hi @kingkong what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: hi Mr R, none yet, just thinking to add that feature to avoid encoding of the same data repeatedly